# How can I dynamically preload the EEPROM on a PIC microcontroller

Tags: pic, c, eeprom, mplabx

I'm trying to set up code to preload the EEPROM of a PIC16F628A with the necessary data depending on the value of one `#define`, so the uC is ready to be popped into a PCB and be used without any extra procedure.
This is what I did so far:

```
__eeprom uint8_t A_RESET[2] = {0x00};
__eeprom uint8_t B_RESET[REMOTEMEM*3] = {0xAE};
__eeprom uint8_t C_RESET[128 - (sizeof A_RESET) - (sizeof B_RESET)] = {0xFF};
```

In this exapmle, I'll use a `REMOTEMEM` of 4, so this should be the EEPROM map:

| ADDRESS | 00 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 | 0A | 0B | 0C | 0D | 0E | 0F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **00** | 00 | 00 | AE | AE | AE | AE | AE | AE | AE | AE | AE | AE | AE | AE | FF | FF |
| **10** | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF |
| **20** | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF |
| **30** | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF |
| **40** | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF |
| **50** | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF |
| **60** | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF |
| **70** | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF | FF |

But instead, MPLAB ends up doing this:

| ADDRESS | 00 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 | 0A | 0B | 0C | 0D | 0E | 0F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **00** | FF | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
| **10** | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
| **20** | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
| **30** | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
| **40** | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
| **50** | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
| **60** | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 |
| **70** | 00 | 00 | AE | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 |

I have previosuly used to have only one variable type `__eeprom`, and I had to write all 128 locations of the EEPROM on that variable. I want to avoid that because now I have that `REMOTEMEM` that can be changed.

Comment: I don't have any experience with the PIC compiler's `__eeprom` keyword, so I can't comment on that part, but in standard C, initializing an array with a single value, for example your `__eeprom uint8_t B_RESET[REMOTEMEM*3] = {0xAE};` does *not* initialize the entire array with that value - it only initializes the 1st element of the array. The only exception to that is if you initialize with `0`, so your `__eeprom uint8_t A_RESET[2] = {0x00};` is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @brhans. I looked up how to do what I wanted and found out about the `{[a ... b] = c}` function in C and it actually works with XC8. Now all the spaces of the array are initialized with the values I want, but they're organized backwards. First, all the `0xFF`s, then the `0xAE`s and at the end the `0x00`s. Do you know any standard way of changing the order of variable creation in memory? Since the EEPROM is not mapped in the memory of the uC, I cannot use `__at()` to fix the arrays in memory.

Comment: @brhans actually in all cases writing {stuff} initializes the rest of the elements with 0. So it happens that {0} initializes the first element with 0 and the rest with 0 so it does what you want. {0xAE} initializes the first element with 0xAE and the rest with 0.

Comment: To enforce a particular order you could wrap all 3 arrays in a struct - something like: `__eeprom struct {uint8_t A_RESET[2]; uint8_t B_RESET[REMOTEMEM*3]; uint8_t C_RESET[128 - (sizeof A_RESET) - (sizeof B_RESET)]; } = { {... initializer for A_RESET}, {... initializer for B_RESET}, {... initializer for C_RESET} };`

Comment: @brhans Please sum up all your comments in an actual answer. This is not a forum. The OP can mark it as accepted, if satisfied.

Comment: @thebusybee IMO this question is off-topic for EE (as it's almost entirely a programming question), so although I'd like to help the OP I'd rather not make an 'official' answer.

Comment: @brhans Good point, and well understood. Wouldn't it be better to point that out and ask the OP to move, instead of "providing an answer"? Did you vote to close? (My reputation is yet too low to see the votes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do agree that at its core the question is one about programming language syntax. It does seem more appropriate to ask this specific question in this forum as the members here are more aware of what the poster is trying to implement in an embedded controller.

That said this is how I did it:
[image]

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: dan1138
 * Target: PIC16F628A
 *
 * Created on August 1, 2023, 11:34 AM
 * 
 * See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/675769/how-can-i-dynamically-preload-the-eeprom-on-a-pic-microcontroller/676147#676147
 */

// PIC16F628A Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSCIO  // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA7/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // RA5/MCLR/VPP Pin Function Select bit (RA5/MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage Programming Enable bit (RB4/PGM pin has digital I/O function, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EE Memory Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection off)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>

#define REMOTEMEM 4

__eeprom struct {
    uint8_t A[2];
    uint8_t B[REMOTEMEM][3];
    uint8_t C[128-(2+REMOTEMEM*3)];
} EEmem = {.A[0 ... 1]=0x00,
           .B[0 ... REMOTEMEM-1][0 ... 2]=0xAE,
           .C[0 ... 128-(2+REMOTEMEM*3)-1]=0xFF
};
void main(void) 
{
    volatile static uint8_t Index, CheckSum;
    
    for(;;)
    {
        CheckSum = 0;
        for(Index = 0; Index < 128; Index++)
        {
            CheckSum += ((__eeprom uint8_t *)(&EEmem))[Index];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use volatile and static on the local variables in the main function?

Comment: @OskarSkog, Because the XC8 optimizer is aggressive I use the volatile storage class to trick the compiler into generating code for the main loop.